# Meteor wrapAsync returning undefined to external service using php connector

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

I've been stuck on this for way too long. Can anyone help show me why my wrapasync method is returning as "undefined"? I'm trying to make a call to Facebook api and have used a php connector that my meteor app should use to talk to the Facebook PHP SDK. My app talks to the my php file and returns simple functions. But when I actually call the external service it comes back as undefined, although when I run the php function in php it comes out fine and returns expected results. Here's the code, everything is server-side:

```
var phpAsync = function() {
    var execPhp = Meteor.npmRequire('exec-php');
    execPhp('C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/Facebook/file.php', function(error, php, output){
        // php now contain user defined php functions.
        php.me( function(error, result, output, printed){
            // `result` is return value of `my_own_php_function` php function.
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        });
    });
};   

Meteor.methods({
    phpConnect: function () {
        var phpSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(phpAsync);
        var result = phpSync();
        console.log(result);
        return result
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that is passed in to [`Meteor.wrapAsync`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) should have callback as the final parameter. From the docs,

> Wrap a function that takes a callback function as its final parameter.
>   The signature of the callback of the wrapped function should be
>   function(error, result){}

So you should do something like this,

```
var phpSync = function() {
    var execPhp = Meteor.npmRequire('exec-php');
    var execPhpSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(execPhp);

    var php = execPhpSync('C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/Facebook/file.php');
    php.meSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(php.me);
    var result = php.meSync();

    console.log(result);
    return result;
};   

Meteor.methods({
    phpConnect: function () {
        var result = phpSync();
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }
});
```

**OR**

if you want other stuff like `output` and printed then you do it like this

```
var phpAsync = function(cb) {
    var execPhp = Meteor.npmRequire('exec-php');
    execPhp('C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/Facebook/file.php', function(error, php, output){
         //IMPORTANT: you need to call php.me only if there is no error
        // php now contain user defined php functions.
        php.me( function(error, result, output, printed){
            // `result` is return value of `my_own_php_function` php function.
            if (typeof cb === "function) {
                cb(error, {
                    result: result,
                    output: output,
                    printed: printed
                });
            }
        });
    });
};   

Meteor.methods({
    phpConnect: function () {
        var phpSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(phpAsync);
        var result = phpSync();
        console.log(result.result, result.output, result.printed);
        return result.result;
    }
});
```

Comment: @so2toll Is it working? If so can you accept it as answer.